# Does FITS file format contain color information?

Tags: astrophotography, file-format

I am trying my hand at astrophotography.

I am using the software Siril on Linux to stack my images. This software uses the `.fit` file extension (for the [FITS format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS)).

It seems to me like FITS is in black and white, and not color. Am I mistaken on this?

Is there a way to preserve color in FITS, or derive it afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siril has the ability to demosaic the FIT file, there is a checkbox on the file conversion tab. I found it best to de-mosaic the pre-processed / stacked FIT file as a last stage, it speeds the processing up on the intermediate steps as you are working on one layer not 3 (Red Green and Blue).

The [siril documentation](https://free-astro.org/siril_doc-en/#Special_case_of_demosaicing) explains this more fully.

Here's the method that worked  for me.

> To process a star trail sequence with multiple dark frames in siril.
>
> CREATE MASTER DARKFRAME.
>
> In File Copnversion tab click change dir and add a working directory eg "siril working dir".
>   Add raw darkframes in file conversion source and then enter sequence name eg darkframes, press convert button. We now have darkframes_seq loaded.
>   In Stacking tab select Stacking Methods > Median Stacking and Normalisation > No normalisation. Then click Start Stacking to create darkframes_stacked.fit
>
> CREATE FIT from RAW.
>
> In File Conversion tab clear source with remove all files from list button then add raws to be processed in file conversion source and enter new sequence name eg P6174240-53, press convert. FIT image files are created and sequence P6174240_53_.seq is automatically selected.
>
> PRE-PROCESS SEQUENCE WITH DARKFRAME.
>
> In pre-processing click use dark and browse to darkframe_stacked.fit then click Start pre-processing. Pre-processed FIT files prefixed "pp_" created and image sequence pp_P6174240_53_.seq is automatically selected.
>
> STACKING SEQUENCE.
>
> In Stacking select Stacking Methods > Pixel Maximum Stacking and click Start Stacking to create the ingle stacked image pp_P6174240-53_stacked.fit.
>
> DE-MOSAICING AND IMAGE PROCESSING.
>
> Check Demosaicing then use Siril Control Center File > Open > pp_P6174240-53_stacked.fit. to carry on in the same window.
>
> In Control Center click Image Processing > Histogram and apply autostretch or alter sliders.
>   Control Center > Image Processing > Remove Green Noise > apply.
>   Control Center > File > Save As > Tiff. Enter file name eg debayered_pp_P6174240-53_stacked.tif and save.
>   Open in Gimp (ideally 2.9x other editors are available) and adjust as necessary (curves / saturation / cloneing) then export.

see https://free-astro.org/index.php/Siril:Manual
and https://free-astro.org/siril_doc-en/#Reference_documentation_1

Answer (score 0):

No, FIT can store color photos (even X-Ray and infrared data :) ). SIRIL uses unsigned 16-bit per channel values (TUSHORT), and images are stored channel after channel on a bottom-to-top, left-to-right order.

I think you have to open your FIT files in another program. GIMP, Photoshop and Irfan cannot show full image and, perhabs, colors, so I recommend you to use [FV](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/ftools/fv/).

**Update1**

Screenshot of FV:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so once I have my finished stacked .fit image, what do I use to convert it to a conventional color image format?

Comment: FV can edit an convert your FIT files to JPG or BMP. Try to open and see store store Siril color components or not.

Comment: So sigil will happily convert your images to fits format, but provides no facility to convert back?

Comment: FV does not offer and export or convert feature. It doesn't even display the image.

Comment: See my updated answer: here is screenshot of working FV with sample FIT-file. Possible you cannot convert image to JPG due to you have not installed additional viewer as described in Help.